# Not able to list all the images

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, awstats, aws-systems-manager

I am trying to list all the images which has the name Ansible*.

If i can pull it off, i can use it to clean my AMI's that are created during patching activity. i am trying it via SSM Automation Document. below is the code i have.

```
description: This document is to remove AMI
schemaVersion: '0.3'
assumeRole: '{{ AutomationAssumeRole }}'
mainSteps:
  - name: getImageId
    action: 'aws:executeAwsApi'
    inputs:
      Service: ec2
      Api: DescribeImages
      Filters:
        - Name: 'name'
          Values:
            - 'Ansible*'
    outputs:
      - Name: ImageId
        Selector: '$.Images[0].ImageId'
        Type: String
```

here, Selector: '$.Images[0].ImageId' gives only the 1st image id of the list. i can get it if i can give something like Selector: '$.Images[*].ImageId' but this is not supported by the SSM document.

could someone please help me on this. all i want is, i want to list all the images with its AMI ID.

PS:  i have the shell and python script which does the job,. but i am looking for AWS SSM Automation document due to roles and policy restrictions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From some quick testing I'm not sure you can.

You can do this on the CLI though, so perhaps you can use the `boto3` library and do it as a Python script via the `executeScript` automation?

CLI command that works:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owners amazon --filters "Name=name,Values=amzn*" --query 'Images[*].Name' --output json
```

Update:

Here's an automation doc that runs the python script:

```
description: Gets all Amazon-owned AMIs.
schemaVersion: '0.3'
assumeRole: '{{ AutomationAssumeRole }}'
mainSteps:
  - name: GetAMIs
    action: 'aws:executeScript'
    inputs:
      Runtime: python3.6
      Handler: script_handler
      Script: |-
        import boto3
        import json
        def script_handler(events, context):
          ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='eu-west-2')
          images = ec2_client.describe_images(Owners=['amazon'],Filters=[{'Name':'name','Values':['amzn*']}])
          amis = []
          for image in images['Images']:
            amis.append(image['ImageId'])
          output = {"AMIs": amis[:10]}
          return output
    description: gets first 10 Amazon AMIs using boto3
    outputs:
      - Selector: $.Payload.AMIs
        Name: AMIs
        Type: StringList
    timeoutSeconds: 120
```

Be sure to change things like region, search string, etc.

Comment: yes, i have the shell and python script which does the job,. but i am looking for AWS SSM Automation document due to roles and policy restrictions

Comment: You can create an Automation document that runs a script in python. It's the first option for "Action Type" in the Builder view, or `aws:executeScript` in editor view.

Comment: No, it's running within AWS and will use the role that you assign the automation when you execute it.

Comment: botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

NoCredentialsError - Unable to locate credentials

this is the error i am getting

Comment: Replace the value for `assumeRole` with the ARN of your automation role from IAM.

Comment: thank you so much. it works. i was trying this for a week. all failed due to this IAM role. now all cleared.